# PGP & Single Sign on

Tags: single-sign-on, pgp, gnupg, openpgp

I am completely new to pgp, as far as i can see pgp is being used to encrypt files and emails.

1) Can it be used for single sign on 
2) Their is pgp  and gnupg (which is based on openpgp) , can anyone tell me what is the difference ?
3) How would i do this in .net

Any references will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There might be some solution for single sign-on using PGP keys, but it's definitely not widespread. Maybe PGP Corporation offers something, you can check...
2. The standard is called OpenPGP. PGP is the name of the company and their trademark. GnuPG is an open-source implementation of the standard. Software by PGP can use some proprietary extensions added by the company to OpenPGP standard.
3. Do what? If you want to implement OpenPGP operations in .NET, you can use BouncyCastle or [OpenPGPBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pgp.php) package of our SecureBlackbox. If you want to implement single sign-on in particular, then you need to learn how to implement custom single sign-on authentication first, then decide how to use PGP keys in the process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I am over simplifying this (primarily due to my ignorance) , but can you use gnupg or openpgpblackbox for sso ?
Is it possible for you to point me to a good resource to learn openpgp ?

Comment: @asp.nerd Single sign-on is more about the OS (or other place you are signing to) than the particular authentication method. You can use GnuPG or OpenPGPBlackbox as a tool that will perform OpenPGP operations but you need to make use of those methods in your infrastructure that needs single sign-on. As for where to read - something is described in http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0072254947 and I think you can find other books. I don't know about good online resources (well, count RFC 2440 and 4880 ;)

Comment: @ Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp Thanks a for the help. Most of the articles online are dated so trying to find my way around.